# Incompatible types TObjectList<T> from decending class

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a base class

```
  TPart = class
  private   
    FPartId: Integer;
  public
    property PartId: Integer read FPartId write FPartId;
  end;
```

And an inherited class

```
TPartTwo = class(TPart)
  private   
    FDesc: String;
  public
    property Desc: String read FDesc write FDesc;
  end;
```

I have a function that loads objects into a Tlistobject

```
function LoadItems<T: class, constructor>(aID: Integer; aInstanceOwner: Boolean = True): TObjectList<T>;
```

I want to pass some `TListObect<TPartTwo>` to `TListObject<TPart>`. Is this possible? Can someone help me to point the right direction?

```
function TPartAgent.GetBackOrderByPart(aPartID: Integer): TObjectList<TPart>;
begin
  ...
  Result:= self.LoadItems<TPartTwo>(aPartID) ; //loaditems give a TObjectList of TPartTwo
  ...
end;
```

Comment: http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/10/generics-and-variance.html